# stat alternative for long file paths

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a program that iterates through a directory tree  depth first (similar to the GNU find program) by recursively constructing paths to each file in the tree and stores the relative paths of encountered files. It also collects some statistics about these files. For this purpose I'm using the `stat` function.

I've notices that this fails for very deep directory hierarchies, i.e. long file paths, in accordance with `stat`'s documentation.

Now my question is: what alternative approach could I use here that is guaranteed to work for paths of any length? (I don't need working code, just a rough outline would be sufficient).

Comment: why does it fail? any error message or code?

Comment: an example would be helpful.

Comment: When processing a directory, change current working directory there. When finished, change back. Use names relative to the CWD. This keeps file paths sent to `stat` very short. Reconstruct long paths when you print them.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Did you even read the question? I know why my code is not working and I was looking for an alternative approach to my problem not debugging assistance. These immediate cries for MCVE's when they would clearly not improve the question are annoying me to no end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are traversing, open each directory you traverse.

You can then get information about a file in that directory using [`fstatat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstatat). The `fstatat` function takes an additional parameter, `dirfd`. If you pass a handle to an open directory in that parameter, the path is interpreted as relative to that directory.

```
int fstatat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, struct stat *buf,
            int flags);
```

The basic usage is:

```
int dirfd = open("directory path", O_RDONLY);
struct stat st;
int r = fstatat(dirfd, "relative file path", &st, 0);
```

You can, of course, also use `openat` instead of `open`, as you recurse. And the special value `AT_FDCWD` can be passed as `dirfd` to refer to the current working directory.

### Caveats

It is easy to get into symlink loops and recurse forever. It is not uncommon to find symlink loops in practice. On my system, `/usr/bin/X11` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.

### Alternatives

There are easier ways to traverse file hierarchies. Use [ftw](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw) or [fts](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fts) instead, if you can.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I suppose my current approach is kind of crude, I will try these suggestions and see which fits best.